# Enhance lookup for lead object

Tags: email, lookup, search, activityhistory

I am facing issue with lookup search. When i go to activity history on contact and click on send email button and click on lookup glass. I am getting enhance lookup search. Please see below screen shot:

[image]

Same when i go to lead page and go to activity history on lead and click on send email button and click on lookup glass.I am getting different lookup:
Please see the screen shot below:
[image]

Kindly help to get enhance lookup on lead object as well.
Thanks you

Comment: Are you using custom visualforce page or standard page layout ?

Comment: Standard PageLayout

Comment: i am not sure but as per my thinking lead does not have enhanced lookup functionality yet. If you are using custom visualforce page then it might be possible to create a custom lookup. For Custom lookup you can refere this link : http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/